# Meaning of "the Washington journalist I.F. Stone"

Tags: meaning

What does "the Washington journalist I.F. Stone" imply in the following sentence?

> The refugees who surround Palestine in their hundreds of thousands were described recently by the Washington journalist I.F. Stone as “the moral millstone around the neck of world Jewry.”

1) I. F. Stone works in Washington.

2) I. F. Stone lives in Washington.

3) Something else.

Comment: You might add that this is a quotation from a letter of Bertrand Russell's.

Comment: Russell died in 1970.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey. I know. I was talking about the text, not the world as it is today. :)

Comment: I know that. I just wanted to place "recently" in context.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant implication is that I.F. Stone *works* (actually *worked*) in Washington.

When he worked for [The Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nation) he was its Washington editor. If his home had been in Boston at the time, that is of no consequence to the sentence, which is about refugees and journalism.

By saying

> the Washington journalist I.F. Stone

the sentence is identifying who I.F. Stone is ([was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._F._Stone)).